# Filter out distinct records and leave last one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database that contains some distinct values like below

```
id     firstName     lastName     someOption
1      mark          tom          28
2      jack          bob          75
3      mark          tom          48
4      mark          tom          87
5      sara          tim          64
6      jack          bob          23
7      katy          jimmy        65
```

I want to select all the table but filter out distinct records instead of the last one like this

```
id     firstName     lastName     someOption
4      mark          tom          87
5      sara          tim          64
6      jack          bob          23
7      katy          jimmy        65
```

How to achieve this with sql?

Comment: What is your MySQl version?

Comment: @Akina I don't know it's on Cloudways XD

Comment: Execute `SELECT VERSION();` - it will show...

Comment: @Akina version 10.2

Comment: MySQL thinks that the last version is 8.0.19. You post from future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.firstname = t.firstname and t2.lastname = t.lastname
             );
```

With an index on `(lastname, firstname, id)`, this is probably the fastest method on larger amounts of data.

Comment: We have like 3 million record :), will test it now.

Comment: @Nameer . . . You definitely want the index before you start testing.

Comment: I test it on localhost and it works, thank you, now I will execute it on the real db.

Answer (score 1):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where (firstName, lastName) = (t.firstName, t.lastName) and id > t.id
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g6dNbKm9GWyfomDHmoGVC9/0).
Results:

```
| id  | firstName | lastName | someOption |
| --- | --------- | -------- | ---------- |
| 4   | mark      | tom      | 87         |
| 5   | sara      | tim      | 64         |
| 6   | jack      | bob      | 23         |
| 7   | katy      | jimmy    | 65         |
```